# не отображается datalist

Tags: php, html, ajax

Делаю поиск, с поля ввода считываю текст, отправляю в поиск по бд через ajax, получаю результат, добавляю в datalist, в коде вижу, что добавляется, а на странице предательски не отображается, хотя клювик в строке поиска, говорит, что в datalist что то есть.
html:

```
  <input type="text" list="for_search" id="search">
  <datalist id="for_search"></datalist>
```

jquery:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
  var len = $("#search").val().length;
  if (len > 3){
    var x = $("#search").val();
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "search.php",
          dataType:"text", 
          data:({search: x}),
          success:function(search){
            $('<option value="' +  search + '">').appendTo("#for_search");
          },
      });
     }
   });
```

[image: результат после ввода]

Пол дня бьюсь на проблемой. Во всех браузерах не отображается. Буду благодарен, если подскажете более подходящий вариант, если этот не совсем правильный. В БД ищу соответствия через LIKE %$search%

Понял, что будет отображаться, если поиск будет соответствовать началу строк.
Т.е. если мы имеем `<option value="Продам двухкомнатную квартиру">` и мы будем вводить в поиск `двухкомнатную`, но наш datalist не отобразит ничего, а если будем вводить `Продам ..`, то работает как нужно. Как то можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datalist не поддерживает fuzzy поиск.

```
<input list="a">
<datalist id="a">
  <option>aaa bbb</option>
  <option>ccc ddd</option>
</datalist>
```

печатаешь `aa` **работает**

печатаешь `bb` **не работает**

https://jsfiddle.net/myfce5fL/

Answer (score 0):

у вас нет текста в option, у вас так:

```
option value=ТЕКСТ> /option>
```

а надо

```
 option value='value'>ТЕКСТ /option>
```